# Configuring an In-comming email setting is showing "The SMTP service is not installed"

Tags: central-administration, administration, configuration, smtp

I want to have the ability to send emails to a list inside SharePoint 2013. so I tried accessing my custom list setting, but under the communication section I did not find any link to configure the in-coming email :-

[image]

so I went to my

> central administration >> system settings >> Incoming email setting

but I got the following message :-

[image]

so can anyone advise how I can fix this error? baring in mind that we currently set the outgoing emails, where our lists and workflow are sending emails without any problem?

**second question** : now I do understand that the "*incoming email display name*" is used to define the email address that we will be sending emails to, but what does the E-Mail Drop Folder represents ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to set up and configure the SMTP services on your WFE server and then set up Exchange to send email bound for your SharePoint list to this SMTP server.  SharePoint will check the  SMTP folders every 5 minutes or so to process any emails for your libraries based on the email addresses you configure for your libraries.

This article describes the steps http://blogs.msdn.com/b/pareshg/archive/2010/04/23/how-to-configure-incoming-and-outgoing-emails-in-sharepoint-server-2010.aspx

And this article targets 2013 but steps are very similar:
https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc262947.aspx

To answer your second question, the E-mail Drop Folder is the location that the SharePoint farm looks at to process incoming email.

Comment: now on the link you send they mentioned the following "If you are not using a drop folder for email, the SMTP service must be installed on every front-end web server in the farm that you want to configure for incoming email. " so does this mean that i can get the in-coming email working without installing SMTP service on our SharePoint server ?

Comment: You need an SMTP service to process the emails being sent from Exchange.  It is the job of the SMTP service to receive the emails and put them in the right folders.  The Exchange Connector you define forwards email to an STMP server, it is not designed to just put email on some remote folder somewhere.

Comment: but if i understand the link correctly, seems  there is a way using the advance scenario to configure the in-coming email without installing the SMTP on the SharePoint server, where in the advance scenario i can define the drop folder location and SharePoint will check for emails in this folder ,,, is this correct ? or i did not get the whole point ?

Comment: The advanced scenario is that you have an SMTP service running on a server that is not part of your SharePoint farm. In other words, not running on your WFE or APP servers.

Comment: sorry about my questions but i am still um-aware of which option i need to have.. now we have an smtp service running inside the exchange server, and i usually interact with this SMTP service from my custom asp.net application (not sharepoint) using asp.net SMTP web client ,, so we have an smtp service on our exchange server,, so does this mean that i do not have to install the SMTP service on SharePoint server ?